# What makes an AD Caster?

Tags: league-of-legends

So, recently I tried Wu Kong out in an AD-Caster-type playstyle, but it didn't really work. So I began to think, what actually makes a champion viable for playing the role of an AD Caster? How should I be playing an AD Caster? What stats should I be looking to build?

Comment: IIRC, Urgot is considered an AD caster, but I can't really remember what separates him from typical ranged AD champions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AD casters deal heavy physical damage through their skillset, and do not rely on auto attacks as much as other AD-oriented champions. Talon, Zed and Pantheon are good examples of AD casters.

AD casters with high AD ratios benefit a lot from extra AD. If they mainly deal physical damage, armor penetration is an absolute necessity in order to avoid being countered by armor.

These two aspects are very often tied together, yet there are a few exceptions, such as Lee Sin's Tempest (E), which has an AD ratio and deals magic damage.

If your champion focuses on DPS (shorter cooldowns, stable damage output, e.g. Pantheon, Riven), cooldown reduction is a very efficient stat. If he focuses on burst damage (death combos with high cooldowns, spike damage, e.g. Zed), you should stick to AD, armor penetration and survivability.

Life stealing is an decent way to sustain in lane (yet not very reliable in a real fight).

Unlike AD carries, AD casters scale poorly on attack speed and critical strike rate (except Garen, whose skills can crit). However, some AD carries are somehow "in between" (Miss Fortune, Graves, Urgot, Blue Ez).

Answer (score 1):

AD Casters rely more on their skill-set for damage as opposed to an AD carry which rely on auto-attacks. One key requirement is for their skills to scale well with AD. Additionally in terms of play style most AD casters will have and use their gap closers to initiate on an enemy whereas an AD carry generally reserves them for kiting.

AD casters generally do not require attack speed in their build, but since their positioning is generally more dangerous than that of an AD carry survivability might become a problem. In some cases early defensive items and careful positioning might be required if you find yourself unable to finish your burst.

It is worth noting that some AD casters are inherently sturdier than others. Unless you are playing someone with a strong initiate (e.g. Riven) then it is best to play as if you were an AP carry, wait for the right moment to join a team fight such that you don't find yourself as the center of attention right away.

Comment: I wouldn't agree on `since their positioning is generally more dangerous than that of an AD carry`. While AD assassins are indeed more exposed because of their short range, AD carries are the real targets in team fights, because of their DPS output. Being very vulnerable, they are harder to protect, so careful positioning is key to survive; all pro players agree on that. Playing an assassin is more about choosing the right time to act.